# Improve delete from

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I need to delete records from a table using another table as follow:

```
DELETE FROM table1 ri
USING table2 ta
WHERE ri.uid = ta.uid;
```

Table1 has 160 million rows, and table2, 14 million rows.

It is taking ages, I added a unique index to table2 and cost didn't improve, is there a way to get this done faster?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use `exists` instead of a "join"?

Comment: how would that be?

Comment: `DELETE FROM table1 ri where exists (select * from table2 ta WHERE ri.uid = ta.uid);`

Comment: I tried explain on this last query and is higher than the original query I posted so not sure this will improve

Comment: This is the cost when using the query I posted originally: Delete on record_instance ri  (cost=3243.39..6357465.29 rows=14344677 width=12)

And this is the cost when trying the EXISTS clause: Delete on record_instance ri  (cost=531947.23..5098865.95 rows=14344677 width=12)

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN plan for the delete.

Comment: We just realized there is a constraint and trigger which takes all the cost, so we will remove the constraint to speed up things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Explain Analyze with a small chunk of data to delete from, we ended up realizing there was a constraint taking all the cost, we removed the constraint to speed up the delete operation, then re-added it.

Comment: Constraint as in transaction?

Comment: It is just a foreign key constraint, for some reason is taking most of the cost

Comment: Are the foreign keys indexed (at both ends)?

Comment: There's an index on 3 fields combined on table1 but on the referenced table there isn't an index

Comment: The indexes should be identical, if the foriegn key is for example 2 fields combined, then there should be an index on these two combined fields on that table as well as on the corresponding table. That should significantly improve the lookup speeds